# Deligne's "Notes sur Euler-Poincaré: brouillon project"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ramification

Is the note "Notes sur Euler-Poincaré: brouillon project" by Deligne available somewhere online? If not, is there a way that I could get a copy of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a copy of "*Notes sur Euler-Poincaré: brouillon project*" (which I received from professors Illusie and Saito). I don't feel at liberty to post it on a public web site, but I can email the notes (scan of 14 handwritten pages) to whomever is interested. Just let me know at beenakker@lorentz.leidenuniv.nl

[image]

Comment: It might be better that somebody writes an email to Deligne, given that he uploaded some letters on his [homepage](http://publications.ias.edu/deligne/section/2582). I also don't know why he wrote "project" instead of "projet" in French.

Comment: @Z.M --- since Desargues' "Brouillon Project" from the sixteenth century, this spelling is not uncommon

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Strange, because the natural topic in French would have been "proje(c)t brouillon", i.e. "draft project" ("brouillon" playing the role of an adjective here, rather than a noun - like "draft").

Comment: @AlexM. --- certainly, I think both the order of the words and the spelling points to Desargue; I have by the way written to Deligne, no response so far, so I'll just keep on distributing the pdf by email "for personal use"

Comment: Oh christ... I had to wait in order to award the bounty to you. So, when I saw that I could finally give it to you, I just clicked on the first answer that I saw and gave the bounty to the other one... I'm really sorry...

Comment: @Gabriel, you might flag this post, or the question, for moderator attention and ask if the mis-click can be corrected.

Comment: @Gabriel --- none of this is particularly important, but you might consider repairing the anomaly by issuing a second bounty...

Answer (score 2):

That project is mentioned in Illusie's article "From Pierre Deligne’s secret garden: looking back at some of his letters" (Japan. J. Math. 10, 237–248 (2015) DOI: 10.1007/s11537-015-1514-9). It isn't the full project, but at least some information about it is available there.